# RJ-45 with magnetics transformer (Ethernet port) connections

Tags: ethernet, magnetics, port

[image]

I am working on circuit having RJ45 connector with built-in magnetics transformer.
The schematic diagram of mentioned circuit shows following connections with Rj45 magnetics connector.
At first I did not connect the RC circuit **(consisting of R17-R18-C10 ,R19-R20-C8 )** to the Rj45 magnetics connector....circuit worked but gave some random behavior.
After that i connected the RC circuit and then circuit worked perfectly...
I want to know- what is the need of that RC circuit in this???...how it helps in improving the performance..??

Any kind of help is appreciated !!!
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without R17 to R20 there will be no line terminations - note the values - 51 ohms on each - these are 100 ohm (102 ohm) line terminators for the data - they ensure there are few reflections when the signal is sent down the cable and reach your RJ45.

In a little bit more depth; imagine you have some pretty normal 50 ohm coax and you put a 1 V pulse from a signal generator at one end - the cable has a characteristic impedance of 50 ohms and it elicits 20 mA from the signal generator when the 1V pulse occurs. Ohms law 1 V = 0.02 A * 50 ohms etc..

This pulse of voltage and current (a power of 20 mW) travel down the cable and reaches the far end where it is expected to find a terminating 50 ohm resistor but finds an open circuit. The power has to go somewhere so it all reflects back up the cable to the signal generator. To do this the voltage at the receiving end doubles in order to force the power back to the source. When you look at it on an o-scope it looks a bit of a mess and mucks-up the data pretty badly.

This is why you use terminators on cables.

Comment: Thank You!! now I got it partly ..and the capacitor is for coupling the high frequency noise I guess...
Correct me if I am wrong!
one more thing is it necessary to connect line termination network every-time??
..because the same circuit have another Ethernet connector without any of this additional components and still works fine..

Comment: If the unterminated connector is part way down the line from the final termination (a matter of several inches max) then no problem. It's the data rate being high (1 bit length being a bit longer in time than a reflection takes to travel up and down) that is the issue and many slow speed data links do not have terminations despite theoretically needing them.